# If $g(z)^3$ is analytic and $g(z)$ is continous, then $g(z)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

To be precise, $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are complex-valued functions defined on a region $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$. My question is, if we know that $g(z)$ is continuous on $S$, $f(z) = g(z)^3$, and $f(z)$ is analytic on $S$, how do we show that $g(z)$ must be likewise analytic on $S$? And furthermore, does this extend to other powers, that is, the condition $f(z) = g(z)^3$ being replaced with $f(z) = g(z)^n$ for some integer $n$?

Comment: The answer in this post by J.Loreaux worth being mentioned: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188359/when-does-a-complex-function-have-a-square-root/188433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the case of complex functions analytic and holomorphic is equivalent (this is a major theorem of complex analysis) we can try to calculate $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial\bar z}$.

We have $f(z)=h\circ g(z)$ where $h(z)=z^3$.

If we suppose $g$ at least $C^1(\mathbb R^2)$ then we can derivate

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}=\bigg(\underbrace{\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial z}}_{3z^2}\circ g\bigg)\times\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial\bar z}+\bigg(\underbrace{\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial\bar z}}_{0}\circ g\bigg)\times\dfrac{\partial\bar g}{\partial\bar z}=3\,g^2\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial\bar z}=0$

And can conclude that $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial\bar z}=0$ whenever $g(z)\neq 0$.

Thus $g$ is analytic at least on $S\setminus g^{-1}(0)$

Although the existence of such $g$ is not straightforward, this is greatly weakening the interest of this method, but somehow explains why $S\setminus g^{-1}(0)$ appears.

For more details on the existence of n-roots of $f$ see the post I linked in the general comments section.

Comment: A problem here is that a priori, we don't know that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}}$ exists. At least in the classical sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm, I see and agree. I'm adding restrictions to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

We need $n \neq 0$ of course, since $g^0$ is the constant, hence analytic, function $z \mapsto 1$, whatever $g$ is.

For $n \neq 0$, we can conclude that $g$ is analytic if $f$ is. If $f \equiv 0$, then clearly $n > 0$ and $g \equiv 0$. Otherwise, $f$ has only isolated zeros, and for $n < 0$ it can't have any. If $f(z)$ is nonzero on a small disk $D \subset S$, then there are $\lvert n\rvert$ holomorphic branches of $f^{1/n}$ on $D$. By continuity, $g$ must be one of those branches, hence $g$ is holomorphic on $D$. Thus we found that $g$ is holomorphic on $S\setminus f^{-1}(0)$. Since the zeros of $f$ are isolated, it follows that $g$ is holomorphic on $S$ by the Riemann removable singularity theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is certainly analytic in $S\setminus\{0\}$. By continuity, the singularity at $0$ is removable, hence $g$ is analytic in all of $S$.

Comment: No, $g$ is analytic on $S$ minus the zero set of $g.$ At the points in the zero set, we can do what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is analytic in 
$$
S\setminus g^{-1}(0),
$$
and continuous in $S$, and hence it is analytic in the whole of $S$ (removable singularities), since the elements of $g^{-1}(0)$ do not have an accumulation point in $S$.

Comment: I get the part about the removable singularities leading to $g$ being analytic on $S$, but I still don't get why $g$ has to be analytic on $S \setminus g^{-1}(0)$

Comment: @NgE-Jay $g^3=f$ shows that $g$ is bounded near each singularity...

Comment: But if we know $g(z)$ is merely continuous on $S$, how does being bounded around each singularity imply $g(z)$ analytic? I think zwim's comment above using Wirtinger derivatives has to be employed to show analyticity. Knowing the Cauchy-Riemann equations holds, I suppose we can then invoke the Looman–Menchoff theorem to assert that $g(z)$ is analytic around each singularity.